# Fix SQL error incompatible types: capture#1 of ? cannot be converted to int

Tags: java, sql, ignite, incompatibletypeerror

I have a SQL query to query an Ignite cache database. But select count(column_Name) gives following compilation error.
`incompatible types: capture#1 of ? cannot be converted to int`

here is my code.

```
private static final String sql = "Select count(_val) from Annotations where  orderId = ? and timestamp <= ? and timestamp >= ? ";
SqlFieldsQuery sqlQ = new SqlFieldsQuery(sql).setArgs(id, t1, t2);
int count = 0;
        try (QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(sqlQ)) {
            for (List<?> row : cursor) {
                
                    count = (int) row.get(0);
                
            }
```

Instead of the for loop, I tried
`count = (int) cursor.getAll().get(0).get(0);`
But that also didn't work. Anyone have an idea what's happening here. Thank You.

Comment: I tried `count = (int) (long) row.get(0);` also. It also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing `?` with actual type?

```
    try (QueryCursor<List<Integer>> cursor = cache.query(sqlQ)) {
        for (List<Integer> row : cursor)                
                count = row.get(0);
            
    }
```

Comment: This, but also a `count` returns a Long rather than an integer.

Comment: `QueryCursor<List<Integer>` here Interger is not allowed.

Comment: You may add an explicit cast or use Object and cast it to Integer when doing row.get().

Comment: Yeah, Later that's what I did. First cast to Long and then assign the .intValue() to the variable.